# SOLR 8.4.1: Unable to upload OpenNLP bin files to zookeeper

Tags: solr, upload, bin

I'm trying to setup OpenNLP feature for SOLR and in order to do this, I need to configure dedicated fieldType:

```
<fieldType name="text_opennlp" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true" >
<analyzer>
  <tokenizer class="solr.OpenNLPTokenizerFactory"
    sentenceModel="en-sent.bin"
    tokenizerModel="en-token.bin"/>
  <filter class="solr.OpenNLPPOSFilterFactory" posTaggerModel="en-pos-maxent.bin"/>
  <filter class="solr.OpenNLPChunkerFilterFactory" chunkerModel="en-chunker.bin"/>
  <filter class="solr.TypeAsPayloadFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

I put required files: en-sent.bin, en-token.bin, en-pos-maxent.bin and en-chunker.bin to the proper collection configuration directory and trigger:

bin/solr.cmd zk upconfig -d ../solr_config/myCollection -n myConfig -z localhost:9983 and get the error:

```
java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doIO(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:75)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:363)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1223)
```

Uploading configuration without those files in the directory works fine (without new field).

I'm using SOLR 8.4.1

Comment: How large are the files? Zookeeper has a default file size limit of 1MB. https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_7/setting-up-an-external-zookeeper-ensemble.html#increasing-the-file-size-limit

Comment: Some of them are larger than 1MB and that was the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Zookeeper has [a default maximum file size of 1MB](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_7/setting-up-an-external-zookeeper-ensemble.html#increasing-the-file-size-limit). Usually these files are larger than that, so you have to adjust the size across your ZK cluster.

> Some Solr features, e.g., text analysis synonyms, LTR, and OpenNLP named entity recognition, require configuration resources that can be larger than the default limit. ZooKeeper can be configured, via Java system property `jute.maxbuffer`, to increase this limit. Note that this configuration, which is required both for ZooKeeper server(s) and for all clients that connect to the server(s), must be the same everywhere it is specified.

Set `jute.maxbuffer` to a size that's large enough to keep your files. You can do this by giving the `-Djute.maxbuffer=...` parameter to the JVM.